# how to make helm hooks retry only one time?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have seen that if my post-upgrade helm hook fails, it retries 5 times before giving up. How do I make sure that the hook only tries once to succeed and give up if failed? Or can I make the helm hook retry only on specific conditions if failed, rather than always?
I could not find any documentation/parameters for this use-case [here](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set Pod backoff failure policy.

As far the k8s doc:
Pod backoff failure policy:
There are situations where you want to fail a Job after some amount of retries due to a logical error in configuration etc. To do so, set `.spec.backoffLimit` to specify the number of retries before considering a Job as failed. The back-off limit is set by default to 6.

Add `backoffLimit: 1` in the pod spec, Ex:

```yaml
spec:
  backoffLimit: 1
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name:
          image:
      
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Full examle:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name | quote }}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service | quote }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name | quote }}
  annotations:
    # This is what defines this resource as a hook. Without this line, the
    # job is considered part of the release.
    "helm.sh/hook": post-upgrade
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-5"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded  
spec:
  backoffLimit: 1 # here
  template:
    metadata:
      name: {{ .Release.Name | quote }}
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service | quote }}
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name | quote }}
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
      - name: post-install-job
        image: "alpine:3.3"
        command: ["/bin/sleep","{{ default "10" .Values.hook.job.sleepyTime }}"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Helm hook to run just *once*, you have to set the `backoffLimit` to 0. That means, it will run and it won't back off, at all.

If you want the hook to *retry* once after running (and failing), then you have to set `backoffLimit` to 1 indeed, but that's not the same thing.